# Error in fetching id of a model and updating a field using the Laravel HasManyThrough relation

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4, eloquent

I have created 3 laravel models Organization, User & Contact which have a Laravel HasManyThrough relation.

I have defined all the required relationships for the Models.

I have to update a specific field named 'deletedate' of a contact which belongs to an Organization.

I used the following code:

```php
class ContactsController extends BaseController
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->user= User::find(Auth::id());
        $this->organization = $this->user->organization;
    }

    public function update_it()
    {
        $contact = $this->organization->contact()->find(Input::get('id'));

        $contact->deletedate = Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

        print $contact->name;

        print $contact->id;

        $contact->save();
    }
}
```

In the function function update_it(),

While fetching the data, all the fields of a contact which belongs to that specific Input “id” is extracted except the field “id”.
Instead of fetching the id of the Contact, the id of User is bieng fetched.

`print $contact->name` This code returns the exact name of the contact that belongs to the input id.

`print $contact->id` While this code returns the id of the User.

`$contact->save()` This code updates the contact's “deletedate” field whose id is equal to user_id.

Defenition of the three models is given below:

Organization Model :

```php
class Organization extends Eloquent 
{       
    protected $table = 'organizations';

    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Contact', 'User', 'organization_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

User Model:

```php
class User extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'users';
    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Contact');
    }

    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Organization');
    }
}
```

Contact Model:

```php
class Contact extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'contacts';
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post in the question the code which defines the tree models.

Comment: @shaddy he has update it

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice that. We really need some kind of notitifaction system for this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Eloquent documentation](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_find) you can see that calling the `find` method fetches all columns from the query generated. So in your case you have two tables joined `contacts` and `users` and users table `id` overwrites the contacts `id`.

In order to fetch only Contact fields, just specify the columns you want in `find` method like this:

```
$contact = $this->organization->contact()->find(Input::get('id'), ['contacts.*']);
```

And then you will have only contact data loaded and the `id` will be the correct one :)

Comment: Great! It really helped :) Thanx 4 the help :)